# Picasso host file changed - cache not

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using this code to retrieve an image from my host:

```
Picasso.with(rootView.getContext()).load("https://domain.tld/directory/imagename.jpg").into(ImageView);
```

I want to use Picasso because I thought that when I changed the picture on the host (same imagename) the picture will change in my App aswell. But it doesn't. So I think the cache is still valid. How long does is stay valid before it fetches the new image?

Comment: Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952627/how-picasso-actually-cache-the-images

Comment: That is what I already thought. Have to do it myself once a week/dag. Gonna figure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you want to clear catch memory and change image every time.
so refer this [link for clear catch memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794891/picasso-clear-memory/30795614#30795614).

other wise set place holder in Picasso lib.
like `Picasso.with(mFragment.getActivity()).load(mCardList.get(i).getProfilePictureFiles().get(0).getUrl()).into(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`